# Is dup2 atomic with respect to writes/read

Tags: linux

Let's say I have a file descriptor 4 that is used for reading/writing with the `O_APPEND` flag for writes. If I have multiple threads writing to this file and let's say periodically I want to switch the file pointed by fd 4, I'd want to do a dup2 call to replace fd 4 with new file. Meanwhile multiple threads will still point at fd 4 for writing. Will I be losing any data or will threads who are writing face errors during the switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux man page and the POSIX description rather clearly say that it is, indeed, atomic:

[Linux man page on `dup2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html):

> The steps of closing and reusing the file descriptor `newfd` are
>          performed atomically.

[POSIX, under "Rationale"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html):

> On the other hand, the *dup2()* function provides unique services, as no other interface is able to atomically replace an existing file descriptor.

I can't see any reason it should be atomic with regard opening, closing and dup'ing the file descriptor, but not with regard to reads or writes.